# Yandex Map (geolocation.get) How to get progress?

Tags: javascript, promise, progress-bar, yandex-maps

When using geolocation, the process sometimes happens quite slowly. At the time of determining the location on the map, nothing happens, for the user it looks like a broken button, and he either presses it a few more times, or thinks that it "does not work." I would like to somehow notify the user that the process is ongoing, for example, showing a progress bar on top of the map, but how to determine this progress?

I tried how it is done in the usual Promise, but apparently this is not written in the API, since there is no effect:

```
geolocation.get({
        provider: 'auto',
        mapStateAutoApply: true,
        autoReverseGeocode: 'false'
    })
    .progress( function(){ console.log("..."); } )
    .then(function (result) {........ })
.....
```

maybe there is some solution?

Comment: When you make the request, display a progress spinner (and disable the button, etc). When the request finishes, hide the spinner, enable the button, etc. (I don't think there's a way to get the progress, since this is done by the client's machine)

Comment: OK thanks. Apparently this is what I have to do.